# failed to start ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to setup kafka and ksql using confluent platform, but ksql is unable to start.

I have followed the steps to install kafka and ksql from confluent using this link https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install 
I have skipped zookeeper config, since we are not using multiple servers and Control center part.
After everything i started *zookeeper, kafka, schema-registry, kafka-connect, kafka-rest, ksql* in this order. While checking status using
command

```
_sudo systemctl status confluent*_
ksql failed to start, while everything else is running.
```

while going into `cd /etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties`

```
(#------ Endpoint config -------)

listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8088
ksql.logging.processing.topic.auto.create=true
ksql.logging.processing.stream.auto.create=true
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

NOTE: I deleted commented part from config file since for (#) it was showing it as a heading here.

Expected Result:

> confluent-ksql.service - Streaming SQL engine for Apache Kafka
>   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/confluent-ksql.service; disabled;
>   vendor preset: enabled)    Active: active(running)

Actual Result:

> confluent-ksql.service - Streaming SQL engine for Apache Kafka
>   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/confluent-ksql.service; disabled;
>   vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since
>   Tue 2019-08-27 15:15:08 IST; 9s ago
>        Docs: http://docs.confluent.io/   Process: 13833 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ksql-server-start /etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties
>   (code=exited, status=255)  Main PID: 13833 (code=exited, status=255)
>
> Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]: 
>   (io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig:347) Aug 27 15:15:07
>   Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]: [2019-08-27 15:15:07,722]
>   ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.serv Aug 27
>   15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]:
>   io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: Could not create the kafka
>   streams st Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478
>   ksql-server-start[13833]:  Make sure the directory exists and is
>   writable for KSQL server Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478
>   ksql-server-start[13833]:  or its parend directory is writbale by KSQL
>   server Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]: 
>   or change it to a writable directory by setting
>   'ksql.streams.state.dir' config  Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478
>   ksql-server-start[13833]:         at
>   io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.enforceStreamStateDirAvai
>   Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]:
>   at
>   io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:
>   Aug 27 15:15:08 Mayank-Vostro-3478 systemd[1]: confluent-ksql.service:
>   Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a Aug 27 15:15:08
>   Mayank-Vostro-3478 systemd[1]: confluent-ksql.service: Failed with
>   result 'exit-code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: Could not create the kafka
>   streams st Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478
>   ksql-server-start[13833]: Make sure the directory exists and is
>   writable for KSQL server Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478
>   ksql-server-start[13833]: or its parend directory is writbale by KSQL
>   server Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]: or
>   change it to a writable directory by setting 'ksql.streams.state.dir'
>   config Aug 27 15:15:07 Mayank-Vostro-3478 ksql-server-start[13833]: at

According to above error, it is permission issue. User running KSQL process doesn't have write permission to create state directory in the given location.

You have to give permission to that user to create directory or change the `ksql.streams.state.dir` to some path where user have write permission.

Comment: I have tried to run the commands from root also, it didn't work . Can you explain how to rectify it.

Comment: In error stack trace, it is complaining about the Directory creation. Did you try to change the path to some other location?

Comment: issue solved after giving the permission to kafka-streams